# Parse XML from python script with in php

Tags: php, python, xml

I'm using a python script from with in php to call some xml date from a c# server. When I pass it through `simplexml_load_string` to parse my data. The python script is called for a few different things, but for one of the calls it gives me

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name

My PHP is:

```
$output = exec("python Auth.py -M authenticate -p 17df30b0-37c1-4ebf-b45e-39353bd971a9 -P 5b9abe609e1ab31555562dd959fc050d");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

My Python is:

```
params = urllib.urlencode(data);
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost", 8003);
conn.request("POST", path, params)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.read();
```

And my XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServerResponse>
  <Result>Success</Result>
  <Token>25027fc3-e3c9-46a8-a1b7-5d217fecfe2c</Token>
</ServerResponse>
```

I can run my Python script from my Ubuntu command line just fine and I wrote the output into a PHP file as XML data and it worked fine on parsing it.

So I don't know what's wrong. Can anybody help?

Comment: please add the xml with your question.

Comment: Have you checked value of `$output`?

Comment: Yes, var_dump 'string(17) "" '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only capturing the last line of the Python print when assigning `exec()` to a variable. And this last line is not sufficient to create a *SimpleXMLElement* with `simplexml_load_string`.

Instead, pass the output stream into an array using the additional *output* and *return_var* arguments of PHP's [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Once you receive the `$output` array, iterate through it to build an XML string:

```
exec("python Auth.py -M authenticate -p 17df30b0-37c1-4ebf-b45e-39353bd971a9" .
     " -P 5b9abe609e1ab31555562dd959fc050d", $output, $return_var);

$strXML = '';    
foreach ($output as $line) {
    $strXML = $strXML . $line;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($strXML, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you, that had fixed the 'simplexml_load_string' but now I'm having a hard time getting the 'array[]' 'key:vaule'

Comment: To my last comment, I needed to check for "result" and "Result"